# After 500 results displayed from DB html/css loses formatting

Tags: php, html, css, sqlite

I have a page that runs off a local webserver that is uses SQLite as its database. As its used local I am not worried about listing all results on one page as they load super fast. I am having an issue with it though as after 500 results are displayed from SQLite3 the formatting goes all wonky and starts stacking them on top of each other. Everything before that is fine. Its written in php. Info was entered into the database using `htmlspecialchars` so I dont believe that is the issue. The code that builds each record in the loop is

```
$list = '';
while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $MovieTitle = $row["MovieTitle"];
    $MovieYear = $row["MovieDate"];
    $MovieRes = $row["MovieRes"];
    $FileName = $row["FileName"];
    $Summary = $row["Summary"];
    $Genres = $row["Genres"];
    $PictureLocation = $row["PictureLocation"];
    $Rating = $row["Rating"];
    $ReleaseDate = $row["ReleaseDate"];

    $list .= '<div class="box">
        <div class="movie">
        <div class="movie-image"><span class="play"><a href="movielist.php?movie='.$FileName.'"><span class="name">'.$MovieTitle.'</span></span><img src="'.$ThumbnailPic.'" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="rating">
        <p><a href="movie-info.php?movie='.$id.'">RATING: </a>'.$Rating.'</p>
        <div class="stars">
        <div class="'.$StarGraphic.'"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="comments"></span></div>
        </div>';
}
```

and i just echo them them in the html as such

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <br>
            <?php echo $list; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some of the data from the database may contain text that disrupts the output, such as html tags themselves. Try using `htmlspecialchars` on anything you print that comes from your db (casting things like IDs to integers also works). It's also way better security-wise (avoids potential XSS attacks).

Comment: Look at the console - and see what's happening with the actual HTML that is built from the PHP. Can we see some of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong, you did not close `<div class="box">` and `<span class="play">` tags properly.

Correct HTML is:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="movie">
        <div class="movie-image">
            <span class="play">
                <a href="movielist.php?movie='.$FileName.'">
                    <span class="name">'.$MovieTitle.'</span>
                    <img src="'.$ThumbnailPic.'" alt="">
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
            <p>
                <a href="movie-info.php?movie='.$id.'">RATING: </a>'.$Rating.'
            </p>
            <div class="stars">
                <div class="'.$StarGraphic.'"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="comments"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aso, you can have some tags or quotes in your database records. So you have to use escaping your variables before output http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Something like this:

```
$list = '';
while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

$id = htmlspecialchars($row["id"]);
$MovieTitle = htmlspecialchars($row["MovieTitle"]);
$MovieYear = htmlspecialchars($row["MovieDate"]);
$MovieRes = htmlspecialchars($row["MovieRes"]);
$FileName = htmlspecialchars($row["FileName"]);
$Summary = htmlspecialchars($row["Summary"]);
$Genres = htmlspecialchars($row["Genres"]);
$PictureLocation = htmlspecialchars($row["PictureLocation"]);
$Rating = htmlspecialchars($row["Rating"]);
$ReleaseDate = htmlspecialchars($row["ReleaseDate"]);

$list .= '<div class="box">
      <div class="movie">
      <div class="movie-image"><span class="play"><a href="movielist.php?movie='.$FileName.'"><span class="name">'.$MovieTitle.'</span></span><img src="'.$ThumbnailPic.'" alt=""></a></div>
      <div class="rating">
      <p><a href="movie-info.php?movie='.$id.'">RATING: </a>'.$Rating.'</p>
      <div class="stars">
      <div class="'.$StarGraphic.'"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="comments"></span></div>
      </div>';

  }
```

Comment: Yeah there most definitely probably is. But why is it doing it after about 500 results but doesn't effect anything before that or fewer results than 500?

Comment: I also put them in the database using `htmlspecialchars` so shouldnt that take care of that?

Comment: @Micha looks like your number 501 record contains HTML tags or quotes.

Comment: You should sanitize content on output and store them as is (just escape against SQL injection)

Comment: I dont think it is a particular record and here is why. When I add more info to the database it just effects a different record that is being displayed at that same point. It happens at about 504 records displayed point

Comment: thats what i get for staring at hundreds of <div> all day ha. Im surprised my code editor didn't catch that. Many thanks. Issue solved. Thanks for being a fresh pair of eyes.